# RegExpr check if a string contains only % or only whitespaces or a combination

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

I am trying to create a regExpr te define if a string contains a % or a whitespace or a combination of the 2.

Example:

```
'%%%%' ---> true
'%    %%%' ---> true
'test%' ---> false
```

can someone help?

thx a lot

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi thx a lot is works!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex,

```
^[% ]+$
```

Check this JS code demo,

```js
var arr = ['%%%%','%    %%%','test%']

for(s of arr) {
  console.log(s + ' ---> ' +/^[% ]+$/.test(s));
  }
```